# google sheets api connection - error JWT cannot be invoked without 'new'

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

i try to set connection to google sheets api with this code:

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const keys = require("./keys.json");

const client = google.auth.JWT(keys.client_email, null, keys.private_key, [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
]);

client.authorized(function (err, tokens) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  } else {
    console.log("connected");
  }
});
```

i get this error when run on vscode:

```
TypeError: Class constructor JWT cannot be invoked without 'new'
```

thank you

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In this case, please add `new` like `new google.auth.JWT()`. This is from your error message.
- `client` has not method of `authorized()`. Please modify to `authorize()`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified formula:

```
const { google } = require("googleapis");
const keys = require("./keys.json");

const client = new google.auth.JWT(keys.client_email, null, keys.private_key, [
  "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
]);

client.authorize(function (err, tokens) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  } else {
    console.log("connected");
  }
});

const sheets = google.sheets({ version: "v4", auth: client }); // You can use the methods of Sheets API by this "sheets".
```

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that your `keys.json` is the file including the valid credential values of the service account. Please be careful this.
- As the additional information, when you want to access to the Google Spreadsheet of your Google Drive, please share your Google Spreadsheet with the email of the service account. By this, you can access to it.